# Rails PDFKit - Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory) when using to_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Whenever I try to generate a pdf using to_file, the process will just hang, and when I stop the development server I get Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - path/to/pdf). However, I am able to render a pdf inline using to_pdf. I'm also able to generate PDFs from the command line in the same folder that I'm trying to generate them in with to_file.

I'm using Rails 3.2.12 and pdfkit 0.8.2. I've tried using wkhtmltopdf versions 0.9.6 through 0.12.4. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Example from controller:

```
html = render_to_string(:action => "show.html.erb", :formats => :html)
kit.stylesheets << "{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet1.css"
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet2.css"
kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/folder_to_write_to/generated_pdf.pdf")
```

Comment: Does the full path of the pdf's file name (sub-folders) exist?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm able to generate the PDF from the command line with wkhtmltopdf in the same folder referenced in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the asset pipeline conflicting with wkhtmltopdf. Added config.threadsafe! to development.rb and it started working.

Comment: I get undefined method when I add that to development.rb apparently thats no longer necessary in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Another issue can be the default options passed. For example, when I left the default print_media_type option in place, found this message in the log:

`The switch --print-media-type, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored."`

Only when I override that does it work for me, either in the initializer or like so:
`PDFKit.new(html, {print_media_type: false})`

The message says it'll be ignored, but it wasn't. It was causing the file to not get generated.